# Greenplum - Install Greenplum on Single Server

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

is it possible to install GP on single server
Which version is supported for the same

Did any one try this? What are Linux packages required ?, Can anyone please share information regarding this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and you can download a VM with everything already installed.  There is a link on http://greenplum.org/  Click on "Get the Sandbox".

I also created a blog post that describes in detail how to create your own VM with Greenplum Database installed.

http://www.pivotalguru.com/?p=1111

Comment: Thanks Jon, It is really helpful, but I want to try installing it at my end

Comment: Check out my blog post that details how to install Greenplum in your own VM: http://www.pivotalguru.com/?p=1111

Answer (score -1):

I have installed it,

Only need to make 2 hostname entries in host file for same server.

I have created mdw for master and sdw1,sdw2 for segments(1+2)